# Relay modern caching example

Tags: react-native, graphql, relay, react-relay

I would like to enable caching in my react native application. I am using GraphQL with Relay modern. I found out that caching is not enabled by default in relay modern, but they have exposed `RelayQueryResponseCache` from `relay-runtime`, which we can add to the `fetchQuery` function in our API. I read discussion [here](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1719) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1687#issuecomment-296842575) about it, but have not seen any example to get started. Can someone help me out on this?

**EDIT:**

Ok I came up with a solution. I think it misses few things but so far it serves our needs. 
I have noticed that passing anything into `QueryRenderer` into `cacheConfig` results passing that value into `fetchQuery` function inside my environment. 
So I have created a `Component` which loads the data by some relation and resolves it into the correct `json` structure requested by the query. Then I return this into the state. Then I extended my `Component` which contains `QueryRenderer` with the created 'cache loader'. Now when `componentWillMount()` is called I ask for the cached data. During this I have set `this.state.loading = true` so I am able to handle loading state. Reading from DB is async.
I am using this class in other components as well. Every one handles its cache data. I just pass it to `QueryRenderer`.

However I was thinking that this makes some extra logic need to add for each `Component` which is supported by this caching. Probably passing the cache resolver as `cacheConfig` and resolve the cached data immediately inside the environment would be much more cleaner.

Comment: I've wrote a blog post about it: http://taiki-t.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/09/05/181931

Comment: Ok this is nice, but how do you update the data? Its nice to have fast response because you return the cache immediately but you do not refresh it with fresh data

Comment: Unless mutate the data there's no such fresh data. Just fetch data from server when you do mutations. Relay updates data nicely if code is written rightly. If you want faster response for mutations try to mimic it with  optimisticResponse: https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/mutations.html#optimistic-updates